# How do i fix Spring Data StaleStateException coming from a javax @Version annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Im building a Spring project where I update entities. Heres is a method I use to do it:

```
    @Transactional
    @CachePut(value = USERS, key = "#update.id")
    public Optional<ClientDAO> updateClient(ClientDTO update) {
        var me = _getClient(update.getId(), true);
        me.update(update);
        clients.save(me);
        log.info(UPDATED, CLIENT, me.getEmail());
        return of(me);
    }
```

Basically, the first time I update it it works, after that if I try to do it again it throws me a:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.manager.daos.StaffDAO#0fa8725b-bc34-4d14-a420-ce6ec6852f8a]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:833) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:820) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]...
```

I have been tinkering with the code using some online tutorials and questions (including here) and discovered that this is probably because of a @Version:

```
@Entity
public class ClientDAO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String description;

    private boolean company;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ProjectDAO> projects;

    public void update(ClientDTO update) {
        super.update(update);
        if (changed(description, update.getDescription()))
            this.description = update.getDescription();
    }
}
```

I have come to the conclusion that if I remove the `@Version` it works without, obviously, updating the version parameter. My question is: is there any way to maintain the @Version (therefore updating the parameter once an update is saved) without having this StateState thing happening? From what I understand its an hibernate but I'm not sure how to fix it in Spring

Comment: have you fixing your issue ?